# Find expected value of a quantity related to the square of normal distribution

Tags: probability

It's a homework problem and I need a hand.....

> Let $Z_{1}$ and $Z_{2}$ be independent $N(0,1)$ random variables.
>
> Prove that
> $$E\left[\frac{Z_1^2}{Z_1^2+Z_2^2}\right]=\frac{E(Z_1^2)}{E(Z_1^2)+E(Z_2^2)}$$

I know the right hand side is $1/2$, but I don't know how to deal with the left hand side.

What I have tried is find joint density of $Y_{1}=Z_{1}^{2}, Y_{2}=Z_{1}^{2}+Z_{2}^{2}$,
and it turns out that it may need to apply the transformation again (get another Jacobian) or
using the technique for finding the density function of quotients of continuous random variable,
but either way looks weird.....

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Note: single-digit/single-letter subscripts and superscripts don't have to be enclosed in braces. `a_b^c` produces $a_b^c$ just fine, and is a lot easier to type than `$a_{b}^{c}$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the expectation of $\frac{Z_1^2}{Z_1^2+Z_2^2}$ is the same as the expectation of $\frac{Z_2^2}{Z_1^2+Z_2^2}$.

Now add, and use the linearity of expectation!

**Remark**: Symmetry is our friend.

Comment: I see!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that we do not even need independence, since linearity of expectation holds in any case.  And we really do not need normality.